# Cellpadding property not work in asp Datalist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

i have a Datalist and i try to make a padding between cells but it does't work.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
ShowFooter="False"  ShowHeader="False" CellPadding="150"  RepeatLayout="Flow" 
HorizontalAlign="Left"  >
```

i change the Cellpadding property but it doesn't work and there is a little space between cells.

Comment: Can you check the generated html on the client and see if there is a difference, sometimes your client css can mess up your asp rendering

Comment: the generated html contain <span> for cells and there is no padding include at all. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

i fix the problem.
the best way is to add padding in the div inside ItemTemplate part